# ASP.NET Web Site Path on IIS: Picture 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-applications

I want to publish my **ASP.NET (C#) WebApplication (MVC)** on my **IIS**.

On the IIS I created a new Application with the name **`testapp`**.

If I navigate to the URL: http://192.168.0.10/testapp my WebPage is loading fine but the picture is not loading (error 404).

According to the DeveloperTools of Chrome the path of the picture is:

```
http://192.168.0.10/data/pic.png  (and that is wrong)
```

The correct path should be http://192.168.0.10/testapp/data/pic.png

In my code I use:
    `Server.MapPath(„~/data/pic.png“)`  to reference the picture. 
    (I guess there is the problem )

I already tried:

```
Server.MapPath(„~/testapp/data/pic.png“)

Server.MapPath(„data/pic.png“),
```

without success.

If I debug it in VisualStudio everything works fine. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to use [`Url.Content(string contentPath)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) method for generating url for the images, css and js resources.

For image in html as example you would write :

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/data/pic.png")" />
```

Comment: No it dosent work, it navigates to the same wrong path.
(http://192.168.0.10/data/pic.png)

Comment: @Enrico may be your route config is not correct.can you show your route config by updating your question

Comment: Ok it finaly works, if it helps someone else: I changed the route config to the right server and in the code I added `@Url.Content("~/data/pic.png")``.